# Creating a floating menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to create a floating menu with [SMINT](http://jsbin.com/kihanako/1). The meaning is that if you scroll down the page, the menu stays up.
The problem is, as you see in the code, the menu is combined from `divs`.
I want a menu which divided with `li`s and `ul`, a regular one, so I've tried to change the `divs`, but the code isn't the same - he isn't stay up when I'm scrolling down the page**;** [Demo](http://jsbin.com/herakava/1/).
I know that it's possible to create a menu with `ul lis`, because I saw the menu at **[Infinity Network Floating Code](http://www.infinitynetwork.com/)**  . It is made with lists nad it is floating when you are scrolling down.
So I must did something wrong in my code if it doesn't work well.


**Q: What did I do wrong in my code or what can I do to make it work?**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You tried position:fixed ?

Comment: @ZakariaDza, position fixed != floating menu.

Comment: Isn't this what you're trying to accomplish? http://jsfiddle.net/JMzLm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lack the javascript logic in order to make this to work. You must detect when the user is scrolling, and when he or she has stopped scrolling, update the position of the menu.

Give your `<ul>` an id :

```
<ul class="subMenu" id="submenu">
```

Add `position: absolute` and a `z-index` to your `subMenu` class :

```css
.subMenu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Then add the following script at the end of your page :

```js
var submenu = document.getElementById('submenu');
var scrollTimer;
window.onscroll = function() {
    submenu.style.visibility='hidden';
    clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
    scrollTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
        submenu.style.visibility='visible';        
        submenu.style.top=parseInt(scrollTop)+'px';
    }, 500);
}
```

This approach will also give you the desired delayed effect (try experiment with the timeout value).

See fiddle (lacks some styling) -> **http://jsfiddle.net/puzN4/**

Comment: At first, thanks.
But, I want the menu won't be dragged, it isn't pretty. How can I make it transition?
Thanks again.

Comment: @rolory, have corrected that, updated the answer and the fiddle. Also made the delay a bit longer. It was merely meant as a prototype demonstration, but you are right - this was ugly and should have been avoided in the example.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't want make you feel bad about your code. I'm appreciate your help.
The edit is good, but I still want to make it transition. I've tried `scrollTop.style.transitionDelay = "2s";` but it doesn't work at all.
Thanks!

Comment: @rolory, see this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/38dsa/ I am not so strong in javascript effects, so I am just using jQuery for the transition effect (if I at all have understood what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you could simply set the `.submenu` to `position:fixed` and `z-index:99999`